# How to configure Azure KeyVault refresh interval with the Azure.Security.KeyVault libraries

Tags: azure, asp.net-core, azure-keyvault

I am trying to configure a periodic refresh of Key Vault values. My original code generated by Visual Studio looks like this

```
var keyvaultEndpoint = new Uri($"https://{vaultName}.vault.azure.net/");
config.AddAzureKeyVault(
    keyVaultEndpoint,
    new DefaultAzureCredential()
);
```

I found one of the extension methods accepts an object of type `AzureKeyVaultConfigurationOptions` which has a TimeSpan property named `ReloadInterval`. It turns out this extension method was a part of Microsoft's older SDK that has been replaced as discussed in this [SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62503022/net-core-key-vault-configuration-using-azure-security-keyvault-secrets). In case the post disappears, the OP encountered [this error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/m5n4d.jpg), which talks about the package "Microsoft.Azure.KeyVault" being replaced with "Azure.Security.KeyVault" and they recommend moving to the latest code. Since `AzureKeyVaultConfigurationOptions` is an SDK v3 object it is no longer recommended.

So if `AzureKeyVaultConfigurationOptions` is not included in the new SDK, what *is* the recommended way to set a reload interval?

Comment: Do you mean [AzureKeyVaultConfigurationOptions.ReloadInterval](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/key-vault-configuration?view=aspnetcore-3.1#configuration-options) with package `Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.AzureKeyVault`?

Comment: @PamelaPeng I think you are right, I mistakenly copied the wrong class name when writing this out. I'll update now. That class is v3, not included in the SDK v4 from what I can tell.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is possible actually using `Azure.Extensions.AspNetCore.Configuration.Secrets`. (Tested with 1.0.2)

As follows:

```
config.AddAzureKeyVault(
    new Uri(Configuration["KeyVault:URI"]), 
    new DefaultAzureCredential(
        new DefaultAzureCredentialOptions
        {
            ExcludeSharedTokenCacheCredential = true,
            VisualStudioTenantId = Configuration["AzureAd:TenantId"]
        }), 
    new AzureKeyVaultConfigurationOptions() 
    {
        ReloadInterval = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(15)
    }
);
```

Comment: Thank you! It seems they added it in that 1.0.2 release

Answer (score 1):

As you can see in the [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.extensions.configuration.azurekeyvault.azurekeyvaultconfigurationoptions.reloadinterval?view=dotnet-plat-ext-3.1#Microsoft_Extensions_Configuration_AzureKeyVault_AzureKeyVaultConfigurationOptions_ReloadInterval), `ReloadInterval` is only used for v3. In the [version 4.x.x](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/overview/azure/key-vault?view=azure-dotnet#version-4xx), there is a similar class for the delay of retry attempts.

[`RetryOptions class`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/azure.core.retryoptions?view=azure-dotnet) is the set of options that can be specified to influence how retry attempts are made, and a failure is eligible to be retried. `Delay` means the delay between retry attempts for a fixed approach. The following shows how to use it in [Secret](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/azure.security.keyvault.secrets.secretclientoptions?view=azure-dotnet#properties), it can also used for [Certificates](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/azure.security.keyvault.certificates.certificateclientoptions?view=azure-dotnet#properties) and [Keys](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/azure.security.keyvault.keys.keyclientoptions?view=azure-dotnet#properties).

```
SecretClientOptions options = new SecretClientOptions()
    {
        Retry =
        {
            Delay= TimeSpan.FromSeconds(2),
            MaxDelay = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(16),
            MaxRetries = 5,
            Mode = RetryMode.Exponential
         }
    };
var client = new SecretClient(new Uri("https://<your-unique-key-vault-name>.vault.azure.net/"), new DefaultAzureCredential(),options);

KeyVaultSecret secret = client.GetSecret("mySecret");

string secretValue = secret.Value;
```

Comment: This seems to be when you manually fetch a secret. How would this integrate with IConfiguration, or injecting the config using IOptions<MyClass>?

Comment: This doesn't work for refreshing the secrets periodically, rather this is setting a retry policy when a secret cannot be retrieved.