# Error : No such host is Known in Asp.net Core Application while configuring Azure key vault

Tags: asp.net-core-3.1, azure-keyvault

I am facing an issue while configuring Azure Key vault in Asp.net core Web API project .

Below is the code snippet as well as error  for reference and I tried to find the root cause but no luck.

[image]

[image]

Error while Run() method execution.

[image]

Exception details
[image]

Please help me out in solving this issue .Thanks in advance.

Comment: What is the details of the exception ?

Comment: I added inner exceptions details , please find it

Comment: what is the host that it is trying to reach ? are you sure this key vault is accessible from public internet ?

Answer (score 1):

It can be issue from .net end  mostly ,`in .NET Core 3.0.100  or 3.1`. This seems to occur when running under the debugger in Visual Studio mostly  and when long parallel calls are made and retrypolicy may help stop this from giving exception for sometime and tries again.

1. So Please try to `Upgrade/Update the .NET Project SDK` if any updates
   available in Visual Studio.
2. Try running with command line

Also in the message of error you can see `retry faild after 4 tries..`

You can check [***ReloadInterval***](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.extensions.configuration.azurekeyvault.azurekeyvaultconfigurationoptions.reloadinterval?view=dotnet-plat-ext-3.1#Microsoft_Extensions_Configuration_AzureKeyVault_AzureKeyVaultConfigurationOptions_ReloadInterval) Property which is used in 3.0 and 3.1

```
builder.AddAzureKeyVault(
    new Uri(Configuration["KeyVault:URI"]), 
    new DefaultAzureCredential(
        new DefaultAzureCredentialOptions
        {
            ExcludeSharedTokenCacheCredential = true,
            VisualStudioTenantId = Configuration["AzureAd:TenantId"]
        }), 
    new AzureKeyVaultConfigurationOptions() 
    {
        ReloadInterval = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(15)
    }
);
```

You could try catching this exception and implementing a retry mechanism for your code if this exception is thrown so that it could try with retry time and delay required for next attempt.
[***Azure Key Vault throttling guidance | Microsoft Docs***](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/key-vault/general/overview-throttling#how-to-throttle-your-app-in-response-to-service-limits)

```
SecretClientOptions options = new SecretClientOptions()
    {
        Retry =
        {
            Delay= TimeSpan.FromSeconds(2),
            MaxDelay = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(16),
            MaxRetries = 5,
            Mode = RetryMode.Exponential
         }
    };
    var client = new SecretClient(new Uri("https://keyVaultName.vault.azure.net"), new DefaultAzureCredential(),options);
                                 
    //Retrieve Secret
    secret = client.GetSecret(secretName);
```

Also see ***[GitHub discussion](https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/azure-docs/issues/33618)***

- If still issue remains, it may be calling several times due to
  network issue also.So please check the `network , firewall and if there is any DNS issue for that endpoint.`
- Check URI if endpoint is incorrect or Managed Identity does not have
  `Data owner` or `Reader role`.Please make sure that you have **proper
  permissions** to access azure keyvault and give proper [***access
  policies***](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/key-vault/general/assign-access-policy) atleast get , list and create if needed .
- Make sure to have one of the ***[roles](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/key-vault/general/rbac-guide?tabs=azure-cli)***(RBAC) provided here to access the
  keyvault .

**References:**

1. [asp.net core - How to configure Azure KeyVault refresh interval
   with    the Azure.Security.KeyVault libraries - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63731389/how-to-configure-azure-keyvault-refresh-interval-with-the-azure-security-keyvaul)
2. [azure sdk .net issues(github)](https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-net/issues/7873)